# Javascript Code not working when on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently installed a code on my website to insert text at the position of the cursor. It works perfectly when on its own: http://www.penpalparade.com/test.php

It isn't however working with my site as a whole: http://www.penpalparade.com/jobs.php

I've tried to fix it but have been unsuccessful, could someone please please help me at solving it because I've been at it for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebug is showing **several** errors.

$(".tooltipbox a[title]").tooltip is not a function

jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander is not a function

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.penpalparade.com/css/images/img02.jpg"

This code is referenced before jQuery:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick='$("#message").insertAtCaret("*****");'>*****</a>
```

To get it out the door move your jquery src reference to the top (in the head tag).

Or to do it correctly.  Just above your closing body tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#whatever").click(function() {
     $("#message").insertAtCaret("*****");
  });
});
```

Change your Html to:

```
<a id="whatever" href="">*****</a>
```

This allows you to separate the behavior from the content.

Comment: IE9 & Chrome - F12 for dev tools

Comment: Don't need IE9, IE developer tools have been there since IE8

Comment: Moved everything to the top quite literally and still getting the following error: "$("#message").insertAtCaret is not a function" why???

Comment: Put it back to your original version because its even worse now.

Comment: still not working, i think theres some clash somewhere on my site

Comment: Ok, i just don't get how its basically the same on both pages but one says it can't see the function, is it ok now?